# XAdES XML Signing - Adding reference inside object tag

Tags: c#, xml, x509certificate

thanks in advance for your help.

I am trying to sign a XML file using XAdES, and using X509 certificate in c#, I am able to add reference to an id inside XML file. However, when I try to refer to external file, I am getting an Exception "Unable to resolve Uri"

I googled, and couldn't find any positive results to my error. Sharing a piece of code that I tried below

```
// Create a reference to be signed.
            Reference reference = new Reference();

            reference.Uri = "test.xml";
            reference.Id = "Id-Manifest";

            // Add the Reference object to the Signature object.
            XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the solution that worked for me!

I had to pass the file as memory stream while initializing Reference object as below and "reference.Uri" value should be the same as file name passed while initializing Reference object

```
// Create a reference to be signed.
            Reference reference = new Reference(System.IO.File.Open(xbrlPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open));

            reference.Uri = "test.xml";
            reference.Id = "Id-Manifest";

            // Add the Reference object to the Signature object.
            XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);
```